# Batch-VBScript Hybrid Speech Script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This is my batch script:

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:a
set /p a=
!d!
for %%G in (%a%) do (set /a b+=1
if !b! neq 1 (set c=!c!-%%G) else (set c=%%G))
echo wscript.createobject("sapi.spvoice").speak "!c!">a.vbs
start a.vbs

exit
```

For every time that this program runs, it overwrites the a.vbs file with the new code as variable c. Is it possible to have "wscript.createobject("sapi.spvoice").speak "!c!"" preexisting in a VBScript and simply have batch assign the variable and execute it instead of overwriting and then executing?

With the help of aphoria, I tweaked my scripts to this:
VBScript:

```
wscript.createobject("sapi.spvoice").speak wscript.arguments(0)
```

Batch Script:

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p a=
for %%G in (!a!) do (set /a b+=1
if !b! neq 1 (set c=!c!-%%G) else (set c=%%G))
cscript //nologo b.vbs !c!

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you another solution?

JScript language is similar to VBScript, but have an advantage in this case: the JScript code can be placed *inside* the Batch file itself via a very simple trick. This way, it is not necessary to create a separated file with the JScript code:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

:: Previous line is:
:: - in Batch: a valid IF command that does nothing
:: - in JScript: a conditional compilation IF statement that is false
::   so the following code is omitted until the next atSign-end

@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p a=
for %%G in (!a!) do (set /a b+=1
if !b! neq 1 (set c=!c!-%%G) else (set c=%%G))
rem Execute this Batch file as a JScript one:
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" !c!

exit

@end

WScript.CreateObject("sapi.spvoice").Speak(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

In this case the original VBScript code is so simple that the JScript translation is immediate; just note that the uppercase letters are needed in JScript. However, I am not entirely sure that spvoice execute the same in JScript than in VBScript; you must do a test...

Comment: I get `BAT(22, 44) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected ';'`

Comment: Yes, it is caused by the difference between VBScript and JScript syntax. Perhaps this is the right one?: `WScript.CreateObject("sapi.spvoice").Speak(WScript.Arguments(0));`

Comment: Yes, that works fine.  I edited your answer to use that.

Comment: This is actually far better for the lack of multiple files, thank you!

Comment: And I understand the first if statement, but why does JScript register it as false and how does this make it ignore script inside as batch?

Also, is 'cscript' a redirection to @end so that the voice feature can run?

Comment: I attempted to implement this into a hybrid calculator but I cannot seem to get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392487/batch-jscript-hybrid-calculator

Answer (score 1):

Create a script file `SpeakNumber.vbs` (call it whatever you want).

Put this inside it:

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

WScript.CreateObject("sapi.spvoice").Speak args(0)
```

Then, change your batch file like this:

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:a
set /p a=
!d!
for %%G in (%a%) do (set /a b+=1
if !b! neq 1 (set c=!c!-%%G) else (set c=%%G))
START SpeakNumber.vbs !c!

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my batch script:

```
@echo off title setlocal enabledelayedexpansion :a set /p a= !d! 
for %%G in (%a%) 
  do (set /a b+=1 
     if !b! neq 1 
         (set c=!c!-%%G) 
    else 
        (set c=%%G)) 
    echo wscript.createobject("sapi.spvoice").speak "!c!">a.vbs 
    start a.vbs 
exit
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont have use a hybrid as you can embed the vbs file inside the batch file.

```
@echo off
set /p "Voice= Enter what you would like to say : "
echo dim speechobject >> sapi.vbs
echo set speechobject=createobject("sapi.spvoice") >> sapi.vbs
echo speechobject.speak "%Voice%" >> sapi.vbs
start sapi.vbs
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
del sapi.vbs
```